# How do I fix VS Code error: "Not able to determine import path of current package by using cwd" for Go project

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm following tutorials and I think I may have missed something.

I have a Go project located at:

`/Users/just_me/development/testing/golang/example_server`

The contents are:
`main.go`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    fmt.Println("hi world")
}
```

I have a `~/go` directory.

go env shows:

```
GOPATH="/Users/just_me/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.9/libexec"
```

I installed the suggested packages in VSCode.

When I save my `main.go` I get:

```
Not able to determine import path of current package by using cwd: /Users/just_me/development/testing/golang/example_server and Go workspace: 
/Users/just_me/development/testing/golang/example_server>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your package is outside of `$GOPATH`, you may need to create a module file.

You'll need to init your go module using

```
go mod init your.import/path
```

Change the import path to whatever you like.
This way you set the import path explicitly, which might help fix it.

The resulting `go.mod` file looks like this:

```
module your.import/path

go 1.14  // Your go version
```

So if the `go.mod` file is in the same directory as a `main.go` file, you can now import submodules from it:

E.g. `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
   "your.import/path/somepackage" // Import package from a subdirectory. This only works if `go.mod` has been created as above
)

func main() {
    somepackage.SomeMethod()
}
```

And in `somepackage/whatever.go`:

```
package somepackage

import "fmt"

func SomeMethod() {
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

Comment: On Windows, slashes are not supported: C:\Projects\Tests\Go\CallbackTest>go mod init /Projects/Tests/Go/CallbackTest
go: malformed import path "/Projects/Tests/Go/CallbackTest": empty path element . Also, it's not clear, what path it should be. Unfortunately, just specifying the last part (CallbackTest) creates the .mod file, but this doesn't resolve the problem in VS Code.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'Callback Your first path element is empty (the one before the first `/`) which is why it doesn't work. What happens when you change it and restart the language server/reload the VSCode window (it often seems to have problems with Go modules)?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Restarting doesn't solve anything, unfortunately. I've ended up with "callback/callbacktest" as the module name. Got the following in VSCode log: Starting building the current package at c:\Projects\Tests\Go\CallbackTest
Not able to determine import path of current package by using cwd: c:\Projects\Tests\Go\CallbackTest and Go workspace:    I.e. nothing has changed for me after restart of VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using vs code, check if the go and code runner extensions are enabled, if enabled, try disabling and enabling again, and if not, install and enable, and download all requested packages.