# Simple Go code running straight from command line but causing "Not able to determine import path" on VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

It is my first time coding in Go. I am following an example and I succesfully can run the small applcation bellow. But I can't find a reason for not been ran in Visual Studio Code. So far I can see, I follow the suggestion found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572507/how-do-i-fix-vs-code-error-not-able-to-determine-import-path-of-current-packag) saying: "... Since your package is outside of $GOPATH, you may need to create a module file. You'll need to init your go module using".

go.mod

```
module jimis.net/snippetbox

go 1.15
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", home)
    mux.HandleFunc("/snippet", showSnippet)
    mux.HandleFunc("/snippet/create", createSnippet)
    log.Println("Starting server on :4000")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":4000", mux)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

handlers.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte("Hello from Snippetbox"))
}
func showSnippet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(r.URL.Query().Get("id"))
    if err != nil || id < 1 {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Display a specific snippet with ID %d...", id)
}
func createSnippet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", http.MethodPost)
        http.Error(w, "Method Not Allowed", 405)
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte("Create a new snippet..."))
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

output

```
Starting linting the current package at c:\WSs\snippetbox\cmd\web
Starting "go vet" under the folder c:\WSs\snippetbox\cmd\web
Starting building the current package at c:\WSs\snippetbox\cmd\web
Not able to determine import path of current package by using cwd: c:\WSs\snippetbox\cmd\web and Go workspace: 
C:\WSs\snippetbox\cmd\web>Finished running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe vet .

C:\WSs\snippetbox\cmd\web>Finished running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -i -o C:\Users\DEMETR~1.EXT\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-go7pNgfo\go-code-check .
```

Project structure (pkg and ui folder are emptys)

[image: tree]

VS Code settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {

        "GO111MODULE": "on" /// *** I tried both on and off with no changes on my issue
    }
}
```

go env

```
PS C:\WSs\snippetbox> go env
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\aa.bb.ext\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\aa.bb.ext\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\aa.bb.ext\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\aa.bb.ext\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\WSs\snippetbox\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\DEMETR~1.EXT\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build201665690=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
PS C:\WSs\snippetbox>
```

In case it is relevant, I added this extension to VSCode

Rich Co Language Support for Visual Studio Code v0.16.1

But all goes fine from command line

```
PS C:\WSs\snippetbox> go run ./cmd/web
2020/08/20 18:19:51 Starting server on :4000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to discussion in Go Slack (GOPHERS), someone guided me to this solution. Hopefully it can help future readers.

1 - add program and cwd as bellow to launch

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/cmd/web",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"            
        }
    ]
}
```

2 - code must be outside GOPATH floder

3 - add go.useLanguageServer": true (C:\Users..\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json)

```
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.toolsEnvVars": {
    
        "GO111MODULE": "on"
    }
}
```

4 - here are my current GO extensions although I don't know how relevant each one is for my solution

```
PS C:\> code --list-extensions
...
casualjim.gotemplate
dunstontc.vscode-go-syntax      
golang.go
```